# vector string character replace in middle of string c++

Tags: c++, vector, replace, find

I am using this code to replace a letter in a string it works fine but it removes the first letter that i need to keep. I only need a * in the centre of the string but this problem has stumped me.

```
textWords[i].replace(pos, 2 , 1 , '*');
```

All the words i am replace the middle character in are three characters long and it always get rid of the first character as well. The replace function is the one used for vectors i did not write it and pos is defined by the code below.

```
 size_t pos = textWords[i].find(bannedWords[j]);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what do you want exactly? If "bar" is a banned word. How would it end up if you used your replace function? "b*r"?

Comment: @fontanini Yes that is how it should end up b*r but it currently show up like *r missing the first letter.

Comment: Check my answer, i think that will work then.

Comment: `if (pos != npos) textWords[i][pos + 1] = '*';` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to replace the second character from each banned word with an asterisk. You have to call std::string::replace using these arguments:

```
textWords[i].replace(pos + 1, 1, 1 , '*');
```

This way you are removing the second character(pos + 1), and replacing it with one asterisk.

EDIT: As @Dan pointed out, you can also just assign the character:

```
textWords[i][pos + 1] = '*';
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly such a simple solution. Don't know why i didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in your replace parameters specifies how many characters to remove. Change it to 1 and it should do what you want:

```
textWords[i].replace(pos, 1 , 1 , '*');
```

Comment: I have tried that and that gets rid of the first letter and leaves the last two. I might not have been clear it is the centre letter that i want to replace.